# PWM use in dsPIC3EV - XC16

Tags: pic, pwm, gpio

I'm learning to use dsPIC33EV and XC16 for a project where I need 4 PWM outputs, but I'm not sure if the PWM outputs of this uC are independent because they are named like PWM1H and PWM1L. Can I use this uC? How should I configure it?

EDIT: In order to explain better what I'm trying to do I have drawn a little schematic. I need to drive a RGBW Led Strip, it runs at 12V and I should use this uC but since the PWM outputs are named as show I'm confused about it, I'm not sure if PWM outputs are independent between them, for example, I don't know if I can use PWM1L1 and PWM1H1 independently.

[image: Basic schematic circuit]

Comment: Can you attempt drawing a circuit diagram?  Even hand-drawn would be helpful. It would help to refine what we think you really want, and then help us to really be able to help you.

Comment: Sure, I edited the question explaining better what I'm asking, thank you so much @MicroservicesOnDDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, unfortunately, you really only have 3 PWM channels, not the 4 that you wish that you had. The H and L are a complementary output pair with dead-time transition to prevent short-circuits.

The H and L pins (PWM1L1 and PWM1H1) are complements of each other, for working with high and low MOSFET's, for motor control, or buck or boost converters (or similar application). In these applications, you don't want the switches on at the same time or you get "shoot-through" -- a short-circuit -- that can rob lots of power at best and destroy chips at worst. Here, I believe, is the [Datasheet and manual for your chip](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/dsPIC33EVXXXGM00X-10X-Family-Data-Sheet-DS70005144H.pdf), where these graphics come from that explain it, at least partially.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your help was useful. I will search another uC which can handle those 4 PWM outputs

Comment: You are quite welcome!

Answer (score 1):

While the 6 PWM outputs of that microcontroller are not totally independent, it also has 4 ‘output compare’ PPS pins that can be configured for PWM.

You should still be able to use this microcontroller for what you want to do.  You could use all 4 output compare modules for the LEDs, all controlled by the same timer.

See section 16 of the datasheet -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the resolution of the "Output Compare" PWM match the high resolution 7.14ns PWM of the three special modules? If not, then they might dim differently, and not present the same. Lighting applications requires high resolution PWM.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD If you operate the modules from the same timer then they can’t dim differently.

Comment: Yes they can dim differently if their supporting machinery is different. All you have to look at is the functional diagrams that explain them. Look again at my screen shot that shows the dead-time compensation, the fault handling, and the current-limiting.

Comment: Can’t see how any of that is relevant to controlling LEDs.  Why do you need dead time for LEDs?  Why would one LED dim differently from another when controlled by the same Output Compare circuitry?   On top of that different coloured LEDs dim differently anyway, so how is any of what you say relevant?

Comment: Dead time is useful for power supplies, to coordinate high-side and low-side MOSFET's so "shoot-through" (short-circuit) does not occur. Implementing PFC would probably be able to take advantage of the tools offered by this chip. And [reducing flicker, for those with epilepsy and other sensitivities](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1789/FlickerTR1_2_26_10.pdf) has added to the burden of implementation specifications in a competetive industry.